# How do Hindus perceive the world?

Tags: vedanta, maya, teaching

Every Hindu believes that he lives in his own world, created by his imagination (Mayan prism), and that all people in his world are just imaginary characters (illusion), in which there are no thoughts, feelings, sensations, emotions and consciousness, and these people do not really exist, they are just imagination, but every Hindu treats these people as if they have emotions, thoughts, sensations and consciousness, and shows compassion for them? Or every Hindu believes that he lives in the same world with all other people and these people also have a consciousness of sensation, thought and emotion?
That is, when I talk to an Hindu he thinks that I am just an imagination, an illusion or a mirage and I have no consciousness, sensations, thoughts, feelings, emotions and memories, but he believes that somewhere there is my world in which I have consciousness, thoughts and sensations, and all other people are just imagination or a mirage that have no consciousness, sensations and thoughts.

Thanks you!

Comment: Vivikta world is not real accoriding to advaita vedanta your statement is distorting the fact.. vivharikya satya means(just consider world is real only for notional purpose) not in real sense.

Comment: @Arnold its not all hindus, only very small percentage who are addicted to advaitic philosophy, hindu is not advaita alone. even all hindus not aware  of this fact that advaita preachs world is unreal. its only some brahmnic community thinks like this.

Comment: that is, almost all Hindus believe that they live in the same world with all other people and all these people have consciousness, emotions, sensations, feelings and thoughts? That is, when I go to India and meet with the Hindus, they will believe that I, like them, have consciousness, sensations, thoughts and emotions?

Comment: Yes living in this world is different from prespective.. from the prespective of engineer/doctor world is composed of different system which repeats itself in sequence, All hindus think that they share this world.. Its yes to all your questions.. and also its real

Comment: Thank you. I didn't quite understand your answer let me clarify if I understood correctly: Almost all Hindus believe that they live in the same world where all people have consciousness, sensations, emotions, thoughts and feelings? When I come to India and meet with Hindus, will they believe that I, just like they have consciousness, sensations, feelings, thoughts and emotions? And that I am not an imaginary character? Thanks you

Comment: @Arnold, you might try searching the HSE with better keywords, alll your doubts have already been answered under appropriate questions via several perspectives